# replace characters in string with regex JS

Tags: javascript, regex, character

I want to replace multiple characters in a string using regex. I am trying to swap letters A and T as well as G and C.

```
function replacer(string) {
    return "String " + string + " is " + string.replace(/A|T|G|C/g, "A","T","G","C");
}
```

do I have the regex expression correct?

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to replace them with?

Comment: If your intent was `replacer('GATTACA')` -> `"AAAAAAA"`, then it's correct. But I don't think that's your intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest combining the `replace` callback whose first argument is the matching character with a map from character -> replacement as follows:

```js
// Swap A-T and G-C:
function replacer(string) {
  const replacements = {'A': 'T', 'T': 'A', 'G': 'C', 'C': 'G'};
  return string.replace(/A|T|G|C/g, char => replacements[char]);
}

// Example:
let string = 'ATGCCTCG';
console.log('String ' + string + ' is ' + replacer(string));
```

Comment: All good answers, but this was the one I was looking for - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way too:

```js
function replacer(string) {
    var newString = string.replace(/([ATGC])/g, m =>
    {
     switch (m) {
          case 'A': return 'T';
          case 'T': return 'A';
          case 'G': return 'C';
          case 'C': return 'G';
      }
    });
    return "String " + string + " is " + newString;
}

console.log(replacer('GATTACAhurhur'));
```

Answer (score 1):

*`A`, `T`, `G`, `C` - Looks like you are referring to DNA base pairs :)*

Aim is to swap `A` with `T` and `G` with `C`. Assuming the input string never contains the character `Z`, a simple swap function using regex:

Note: Change `Z` with another character or symbol that you are confident will not appear in the input string. Example `$` maybe?

```js
var input = "AAATTGGCCTAGC"
input = input.replace(/A/g,"Z").replace(/T/g,"A").replace(/Z/g,"T");
input = input.replace(/G/g,"Z").replace(/C/g,"G").replace(/Z/g,"C");
console.log(input);
```